# Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Router'

Tags: angular

I want to pass id from one component to another component. I'm using example code that i've found on the internet that use params. But when i try the method i got an error  `Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Router'.` I already put params in `contsructor`

Below are my service and my component.

```
service.ts

getDetails(id: number) {
    console.log(id);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/viewtask/?process='+ id, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }


component.ts



import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { OAuthService } from "angular-oauth2-oidc";
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { JobService } from "../../../shared/job.service";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './process.component.html',
  providers: [ JobService ],

})


    export class ProcessComponent {

      private data : Object;
      navigated = false;

     constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService, private router: Router, private jobService: JobService, private param: Params) {

     }

        public getProcess(){

          this.router.params.forEach((params: Params) => { // <------  error params start here
          if (params['id'] !== undefined) {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this.navigated = true;
            this.jobService.getDetails(id).subscribe(
              data => {
              let i = 0;
              for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                this.data = data;

          }
          },
          );
          }

    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean to use `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: @peeskillet still the same error even i'm use `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: That's odd. Can you show the full code where you are using it (constructor included)

Comment: And where are you using `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: @peeskillet i remove it.. And i put it back just now.. it works.. No error.. Thank you thank youu...

Comment: @peeskillet but i got this warning `export 'Params' was not found in '@angular/router'`

Comment: Remove `Params` from `import { Router, Params } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: @echonax if i remove it..i had an `cannot find name 'param'`

Comment: @uetoaya then remove the `param: Params` from the constructor also? Are you using it?

Comment: @echonax yes i remove it in construstor also.. i'm using it in my `getProcess()`function

Comment: @uetoaya ah didn't see that one, my bad

Comment: @echonax i need to remove `.forEach((params: Params)` and change it like this `.forEach((params)` and then it works.. Thank youu

Comment: Ah cool. Glad you figured it out :-)